# Is it possible to set a machinekey for an Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, machinekey

I have hosted an Owin WebAPI Server in an Azure Worker Role.
The Owin Authentication middleware seems to use the MachineKey to encrypt and generate Tokens.
This works perfectly when I have only one instance of this role, but as soon as I want to use several instances, the tokens generated by each instance are differents.

This is the same problem as a web farm, Azure automatically solves this for WebRoles using the same .net Machine Key for all instances  in Web.config.

But this does not work for Worker Role instances.

Is there a trick to have Azure using the same machine key for all the intsances of a worker Role ?

Seems it would be easier than rewriting code to generate the tokens for Owin.

Comment: How about just manually setting the machine key in your application configuration file? It works pretty well with a traditional Web Role, should't have issues with a worker role, too. I repeat - set the key manually in config, don't rely on auto configuration!

Comment: Thanks for answers, but App.config does not support setting machine ket as Web.config does...

Comment: and what stops you from having `system.web\machineKey` section in your app.config file? did you try before replying?

Comment: Yes refused on loading

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 4):

If your self-hosted application can reference `System.Web`, then you can use the same [MachineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Security.MachineKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) implementaiton that the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` does.

Put the `configuration/system.web/machineKey` settings in your App.config just like it is in the Web.config.

Reference reference `System.Web` and add the following class:

```
public class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(params string[] purposes)
    {
        this.purposes = purposes;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Protect(userData, this.purposes);
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, this.purposes);
    }
}
```

Then set your authentication options using that class:

```
        var authenticationOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
                                    {
                                        AccessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyDataProtector(
                                            typeof(OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware).Namespace, "Access_Token", "v1")),
                                        AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider(),
                                    };
```