# Is machine key shared between Azure App Service instances?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, katana, machinekey, azure-web-app-service

If I scale out my azure app service, **are all the instances sharing the same machine key**? I want to use app service for my website with Web API 2.0 + Katana middleware and tokens are issued and validated using the machine key. Azure documentation does not provide any answer.

I made some tests and it seems that the key is shared.

Answer (score 1):

Logically seen they are not seeing they are different machines.

The system should be independent of machine keys as well. If for example you do an update of your app and you swap staging and production environments you would want the system to be able to continue.

On this other question you can see a possible workaround: [Is it possible to set a machinekey for an Azure Worker Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028672/is-it-possible-to-set-a-machinekey-for-an-azure-worker-role)